# Google Play: Version XX is not served to any device configuration error after developer account reinstated

Tags: android

Our developer account was suspended and was reinstated. All our apps were removed from store.  We are trying to resubmit new versions of all the apps with new code but I've discovered that if I don't re-submit the apps for publication FIRST I am hitting the following problem, and unfortunately for the 2 that I did this for I can't seem to resolve it or reverse it.

Here's the issue:

When I submit a new APK I get the error "Version 44 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 44 would receive version 47"

Now I've read all the other questions/answers from other people who've had a similar issue and tried all of the following - none of these work:

- Tried just deactivating version 44
- Tried deactivating version 44 and moving version 47 to Alpha (and Beta as well)
- Tried deleting Version 47
- Tried publishing Version 47 as a staged rollout
- Tried all of the above after clearing my browser cache
- Tried all of the above on a different browser

I'm at a loss.  Can't figure out how to get around this apparent bug in Google!  It basically won't let me do ANYTHING at this point to republish the app.

Any ideas, anyone?   This is happening on 2 of our apps, both of which I did not republish first before submitting a new version.